# ReactD3: series attribute is not found in reactD3Basic object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-d3

I'm trying to use reactd3 library in my project.
And I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactD3Basic.series) is not a function
```

In the line (in the library code):

```
var chartSeriesData = (0, _reactD3Basic.series)(this.props);
```

Because `_reactD3Basic` doesn't contain attribute series.
Can you help me? Why is it?

Answer (score 0):

I am hitting this as well. One hint is that it may be related to Babel compiler version, similar to this: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1694

Did you end up finding a resolution? As I am still stuck as well

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured out the problem and filed an issue:

https://github.com/react-d3/react-d3-brush/issues/6

Basically, react-d3-brush is out of date with the other projects. First off, series is no longer in react-d3-basic. It nows lives in react-d3-shape. Which is why series can't be found. The babel compiler thing relates to the treatment of "export default", which also has to be tweaked in react-d3-brush, the other libraries are already up to date.

Solution is to fork react-d3-brush and bring it up to date.